# Magento 2 Customer API Token refresh

Tags: magento2, customer, rest-api, graphql, app

I am developing an APP based on magento 2 ecommerce.

As any APP,  the user should never logged out.

I can get with magento 2 a token for any customer by that token have an expery time.

I know that I can modify that expire time but what I need is some method to refresh the token with the same token itself or get another new token.

Also I don't want to store customer data on client side because its risky.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you find a solution?